# Unwanted fluid simulation clumping

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm running this fluid simulation at a small scale (real-world scale) and I find that the water particles clump together into balls?

I can't seem to find the setting to make it more like a constant flow and would love a hint on what to tweak to achieve the goal?

The image below shows the unwanted status quo.

[image]

Comment: try increasing the resolution of the domain or minimum timesteps

Comment: Thanks, I've been tweaking these numbers, but maybe I haven't raised them high enough for the desired effect. I'll report back once I've run the sim a few more times.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments left on the question, I was able to solve this issue by increasing the resolution divisions on the domain.
Originally I was running it at +/-128, but had to bring it up to 256, 320, and even 512 until I started seeing the results I was hoping for.

Comment: You might also try playing with reducing particle radius.  Sometimes various combinations can save on simulation time.